# MXE Qt5 application builds fail in Docker container

Tags: c++, docker, qt5, mxe

So, I have successfully built MXE and Qt5 (`make qt5`) in a Docker container (based on Ubuntu 18.04) and copied the stuff in `/opt/mxe` and appended `PATH` with `/opt/mxe/usr/bin`.

However, when I try to build my Qt5 application inside the container it fails with both qmake and CMake. For some reason the Qt tools somehow don't work properly. Here's the output from qmake:

```
# i686-w64-mingw32.static-qmake-qt5 ../heimer.pro 
Project MESSAGE: Building for Qt version 5.11.1.
Project MESSAGE: Building for Qt version 5.11.1.
Project MESSAGE: Building for Qt version 5.11.1.
RCC: Error in '../data/icons/icons.qrc': Cannot find file 'heimer.png'
RCC: Warning: No resources in '../data/icons/icons.qrc'.
RCC: Error in '../data/images/images.qrc': Cannot find file 'about.png'
RCC: Error in '../data/images/images.qrc': Cannot find file 'add.png'
RCC: Error in '../data/images/images.qrc': Cannot find file 'colors.png'
RCC: Warning: No resources in '../data/images/images.qrc'.
RCC: Error in '../data/translations/translations.qrc': Cannot find file     'heimer_fi.qm'
RCC: Warning: No resources in '../data/translations/translations.qrc'.
RCC: Error in '../data/icons/icons.qrc': Cannot find file 'heimer.png'
RCC: Warning: No resources in '../data/icons/icons.qrc'.
RCC: Error in '../data/images/images.qrc': Cannot find file 'about.png'
RCC: Error in '../data/images/images.qrc': Cannot find file 'add.png'
RCC: Error in '../data/images/images.qrc': Cannot find file 'colors.png'
RCC: Warning: No resources in '../data/images/images.qrc'.
RCC: Error in '../data/translations/translations.qrc': Cannot find file 'heimer_fi.qm'
RCC: Warning: No resources in '../data/translations/translations.qrc'.
```

The resource compiler cannot find anything.

CMake build fails like this:

```
# i686-w64-mingw32.static-cmake --build .
== Using MXE wrapper: /opt/mxe/usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32.static-cmake
== Skip using MXE toolchain: /opt/mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/share/cmake/mxe-conf.cmake
Scanning dependencies of target heimer_autogen
[  1%] Automatic MOC for target heimer

AutoMoc subprocess error
------------------------
moc failed for "/heimer/src/nodehandle.hpp"

Command
-------
/opt/mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/bin/moc -I/heimer/build-mxe-cmake-docker/src -I/heimer/src -I/heimer/build-mxe-cmake-docker    /src/heimer_autogen/include -I/heimer/src/contrib -I/heimer/build-mxe-cmake-docker -I/opt/mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/include -I/opt/mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/include/QtWidgets -I/opt/mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/include/QtGui -I/opt/mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/include/QtCore -I/opt/mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/./mkspecs/win32-g++ -I/opt/mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/include/QtXml -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_XML_LIB "-DVERSION=\"0.0.0\"" -o /heimer/build-mxe-cmake-docker/src/heimer_autogen/EWIEGA46WW/moc_nodehandle.cpp /heimer/src/nodehandle.hpp

Output
------
/heimer/src/nodehandle.hpp:28: Error: Undefined interface
```

Let's check the Qt configuration inside the container:

```
# /opt/mxe/usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32.static-qmake-qt5 -query
QT_SYSROOT:
QT_INSTALL_PREFIX:/opt/mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5
QT_INSTALL_ARCHDATA:/opt/mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5
QT_INSTALL_DATA:/opt/mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5
QT_INSTALL_DOCS:/opt/mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/doc
QT_INSTALL_HEADERS:/opt/mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/include
QT_INSTALL_LIBS:/opt/mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/lib
QT_INSTALL_LIBEXECS:/opt/mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/bin
QT_INSTALL_BINS:/opt/mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/bin
QT_INSTALL_TESTS:/opt/mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/tests
QT_INSTALL_PLUGINS:/opt/mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/plugins
QT_INSTALL_IMPORTS:/opt/mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/imports
QT_INSTALL_QML:/opt/mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/qml
QT_INSTALL_TRANSLATIONS:/opt/mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/translations
QT_INSTALL_CONFIGURATION:/opt/mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/etc/xdg
QT_INSTALL_EXAMPLES:/opt/mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/examples
QT_INSTALL_DEMOS:/opt/mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/examples
QT_HOST_PREFIX:/opt/mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5
QT_HOST_DATA:/opt/mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5
QT_HOST_BINS:/opt/mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/bin
QT_HOST_LIBS:/opt/mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/lib
QMAKE_SPEC:linux-g++
QMAKE_XSPEC:win32-g++
QMAKE_VERSION:3.1
QT_VERSION:5.11.1
```

Seems to be ok.

Of course my application compiles perfectly on my host machine with or without MXE and with both qmake and CMake.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running the docker container with `--privileged` solved the issue.